# Import an Excel File data to Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to import an excel file to a datagrid in WPF. What I've found around the Internet won't rally do the trick.

I have a code that opens and reads excelfiles and outputs the data cells to a messagebox. I want to do so but to DataGrid instead. Here follows the code that needs to be changed:

```
private void ReadFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Temp\vitoshacademy.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        //iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
        //excel is not zero based!!
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //new line
                if (j == 1)
                    MessageBox.Show("\r\n");

                //write the value to the console
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
            }
        }

        //cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);


    }
```

Comment: You can query an excel sheet using OleDB. https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: I know that but I am required to use using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; instead.

Comment: You might consider using open xml sdk, that way you don't have to depend on the users having excel installed for your program to work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Answer (score 1):

**To Import the Excel file into DataGrid using C# in WPF**

```
  Using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
  private async void btnImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
        choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string sFileName = choofdlog.FileName;
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(choofdlog.FileName);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
            {
                System.Data.DataTable td = new System.Data.DataTable();
                td = await Task.Run(() => formofDataTable(ws));
                ds.Tables.Add(td);//This will give the DataTable from Excel file in Dataset
            }
            Datagrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            wb.Close();
        }
    }
    public System.Data.DataTable formofDataTable(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        string worksheetName = ws.Name;
        dt.TableName = worksheetName;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = ws.UsedRange;
        object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
        for (int k = 1; k <= valueArray.GetLength(1); k++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add((string)valueArray[1, k]);  //add columns to the data table.
        }
        object[] singleDValue = new object[valueArray.GetLength(1)]; //value array first row contains column names. so loop starts from 2 instead of 1
        for (int i = 2; i <= valueArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < valueArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (valueArray[i, j + 1] != null)
                {
                    singleDValue[j] = valueArray[i, j + 1].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    singleDValue[j] = valueArray[i, j + 1];
                }
            }
            dt.LoadDataRow(singleDValue, System.Data.LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
        }
    
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: This will give you the Importing the Excel into DataTable, and that can be bind in DataGrid